# Not supported cipher version

Tags: magento2.2.7

I'm running into an issue on **Magento 2.2.7** after a failed rollback from **2.3**

> Exception: Not supported cipher version in /vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php:135

Current PHP version is **7.1.** I've tried **7** and **7.2**
I've cleared **`var/cache`** and **`var/page_cache`**

How can I clear this error please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case this came from an inconsistency between magento version of DB and Source.

I had a 2.3.0 database with a 2.2.6 code.

Comment: So how did you resolve it? I understand you upgraded to 2.3 and then later tried to go back to 2.2.6, but how did you actually resolve it? In my case, I reinstalled 2.1 and restored the 2.1 database and still get the same error.

Comment: This is not a resolution and should not be the accepted answer.

The advise should be to make sure you are on the correct branch for your database. If you have a database on a newer version, but the code is old then the chances are you are checked out to the wrong branch.

Comment: This is the right reason of the issue, but doesn't contain the resolve. Check "Peter Lembke" answer below for the resolve.

Answer (score 22):

If you run code for Magento 2.2.x on a Magentyo 2.3.x database then some of the encrypted strings in table core_config_data might use a cipher that is not available in Magento 2.2.x

In Magento 2.2.x you have three cipher methods numbered from 0 to 2. Magento 2.3 support more chipher methods.

If you run:

```
select * from core_config_data where value like '%0:3:%'
```

then you can see if the database contain any config settings that Magento 2.2.x can not decrypt.

In my case I had a Magento 2.2.6 database except for the core_config_data that came from a Magento 2.3.1 database. I could just delete those strings and lose those settings.

```
update core_config_data set value = '' where value like '%0:3:%'
```

Comment: This indeed is the right answer.

Comment: Perfect answer..!!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to others, I experienced this problem while upgrading from 2.2.8 to 2.3.1 and in my case, I needed to restart php-fpm and nginx to fix it.  I use an automated build tool that creates versioned directories to deploy Magento to.  So while the database base was upgraded to 2.3.1, due to caching within php-fpm/nginx, the web server still pointed to the older 2.2.8 (i.e. previous version) release folder.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across with this problem today when I imported a Magento 2.3.2 database in a Magento 2.2.9 code.

So, I updated the Magento from 2.2.9 to version 2.3.2 following Magento 2.3 docs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

After that, you need to refresh the cache. In my case I use Redis, so I typed on the terminal the command `redis-cli flushall` and Magento is working fine now.

Answer (score -2):

You need to revert the changes in the **`etc/config.php`** and **`etc/env.php`** file. And clear all cache.
 It will resolve the issue.